# DataTable: change the order in which the Show Entries filter and the Search box filter appear

Tags: jquery, datatables

Is it possible to do this without using CSS to force them to appear in a different order?

I want the search box to render before the show entries drop down but by default its always the other way round.

Comment: Yes, you can use the `dom` option: https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom. However modifying their positions with CSS is *far* easier.

Comment: you may be right - i just used jQuery to successfully add a class of pull right to the first div (as they both render with the col-sm-6 class). ill look at that link u sent

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I cannot imagine something more easy than reorder the content of a string 6 chars strong :) Or copy paste the examples from the documentation.